# Assign integer to optionmenu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried to assign integer values to my optionmenu. When I try to calculate the sum from the calculate function, only bmr and tef are being calculated I have used dictionaries to store values associated to the choices for the optionmenus.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Calorie Calculator")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Weight").grid(column = 0, row = 0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "Enter weight in kilos").grid(column = 2, row = 0)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "BMR is").grid(column = 0, row = 1)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "TEF is").grid(column = 0, row = 2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "EEE").grid(column = 0, row = 3)
Label(mainframe, text = "Enter excersise activity").grid(column = 2, row = 3)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text = "NEAT").grid(column = 0, row = 4)
Label(mainframe, text = "Does your job require you to be physically active?").grid(column = 2, row = 4)

bmr = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = bmr).grid(column = 1, row = 1)

tef = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = tef).grid(column = 1, row = 2)

tdee = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable = tdee).grid(column = 1, row = 6)

exercise_vals = {"Light": 250, "Moderate": 325, "Advanced": 425, "Athlete": 500}
exercise = StringVar()
drop_eee = OptionMenu(mainframe, exercise, *exercise_vals).grid(column = 1, row = 3)

job_activity_vals = {"Yes": 250, "No": 500}
job_activity = StringVar()
drop_neat = OptionMenu(mainframe, job_activity, *job_activity_vals).grid(column = 1, row = 4)


weight = StringVar()
weight_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable = weight).grid(column = 1, row = 0)

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        weight_val = float(weight.get())
        bmr_val = weight_val * 20
        bmr_val = bmr.set(bmr_val)
        tef_val = float(bmr.get()) * 0.1
        tef_val = tef.set(tef_val)
        eee_val = float(exercise.get())
        neat_val = float(job_activity.get())
        tdee_val = bmr_val + tef_val + eee_val + neat_val
        tdee_val = tdee.set(tdee_val)
    except ValueError:
        pass

ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Calculate TDEE", command = calculate).grid(column = 2, row = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error occurred is ignored by `try`. Remove it and code and use it with appropriate settings only. There are alot of errors that occur here. Starting from `ValueError` till `TypeError`. You should try to learn what all of this means first and then write this code from scratch. You also forgot to do the indexing with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used `try / except` to ignore the `ValueError` which occurs on `float(exercise.get())` and `float(job_activity.get())`.  That is why you don't get the result for `tdee`.

The `ValueError` raised is due to:

- `exercise.get()` will return something like `Light`, `Moderate`, etc
- `job_activity.get()` will return something like `Yes` or `No`

Therefore using `float()` on these values will raise `ValueError`.

You should get the values from the dictionaries `exercise_vals` and `job_activity_vals` instead.

Also the following lines:

- `bmr_val = bmr.set(bmr_val)`
- `tef_val = tef.set(tef_val)`

will assign `None` to `bmr_val` and `tef_val`.

Below is the modified `calculate()` to fix the above issues:

```py
def calculate(*args):
    try:
        weight_val = float(weight.get())

        bmr_val = weight_val * 20
        bmr.set(bmr_val)
        
        tef_val = float(bmr.get()) * 0.1
        tef.set(tef_val)

        eee_val = float(exercise_vals[exercise.get()]) # get value from dictionary
        neat_val = float(job_activity_vals[job_activity.get()]) # get value from dictionary

        tdee_val = bmr_val + tef_val + eee_val + neat_val
        tdee.set(tdee_val)
    except ValueError as e:
        # better show the error message instead of ignoring it
        print("ValueError", e)
```